# Javascript getting the Leap Year

Tags: javascript

I need help with my code. I need to call my function leapYear() to my FieldValidator() function to determine if the year given by the user is leap year or not.

Here is my code:

```
function FieldValidator() {
     var err = "";
     var valid = false;
     var leap = new leapYear(year)
     //year
     if(document.getElementById('year').value == ""){
        valid = true;
        err += "Enter year \n";
        document.getElementById('year').style.borderColor = "red";
     }
     else if(document.getElementById('year').value < 1000 || document.getElementById('year').value > 9999){
        valid = true;
        err += "Invalid Year \n";
        document.getElementById('year').style.borderColor = "red";
     }
     else {
        document.getElementById('year').style.borderColor = "green";
     }
     //month
     if(document.getElementById('month').value == ""){
        valid = true;
        err += "Enter Month \n";
        document.getElementById('month').style.borderColor = "red";
     }

     else if(document.getElementById('month').value < 1 || document.getElementById('month').value > 12){
        valid = true;
        err += "Invalid Month\n";
        document.getElementById('month').style.borderColor = "red";
     }
     else {
        document.getElementById('month').style.borderColor = "green";
     }
     //day
     if(document.getElementById('day').value == ""){
        valid = true;
        err += "Enter day \n";
        document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "red";
     }
     else if (document.getElementById('month').value == 2) {
        if(document.getElementById('year').value == leap()) {
            if(document.getElementById('day').value > 29) {
                valid = true;
                err += "invalid leap\n";
                document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "red";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "green";
            }
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('year').value != leap()) {
            if(document.getElementById('day').value > 28) {
                valid = true;
                err += "invalid \n";
                document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "red";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "green";
            }
        }
     }
     else if (document.getElementById('month').value != 2) {
        if(document.getElementById('day').value < 1 || document.getElementById('day').value > 31 ) {
            valid = true;
            err += "Invalid day \n";
            document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "red";
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "green";
        }
     }
     else {
        document.getElementById('day').style.borderColor = "green";
     }

     if(valid){
        alert(err)
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}

function leapYear(year)
{
    return ((document.getElementById('year').value % 4 == 0) && (document.getElementById('year').value % 100 != 0)) || (document.getElementById('year').value % 400 == 0);
}
```

Comment: It's best to usually ask a minimal, complete, and verifiable question instead of posting so much code that is not relevant to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the error keeping you from calling the method? Is there an error message or unexpected result?

Comment: the problem is it doesn't get the leapYear function on my FieldValidator function.

Comment: In your function you are calling a non existent function `leap()` instead of using the boolean value `leap` which you correctly computed by calling the `leapYear()` function.

Comment: @spirographer how can i call the leapYear() function to my if condition?

Comment: Use the boolean value `leap` that you computed at the beginning of the function.  Hint: replace the long and incorrect expression `document.getElementById('year').value != leap()` in the two places you use it.  Also you should probably compute a few variables at the beginning like `year = document.getElementById('year').value` so you don't use the expression over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

For anything time related, I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) (either like you in the browser or on the server in nodejs).

It's as simple as this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js">
var year = 2015;

moment([year]).isLeapYear(); // false
</script>
```

The isLeapYear function itself is quit simple, too. So you can use that to determine if the year is a leap year or not.

```
function isLeapYear(year) {
    return (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/f3fbef9d9875bbff340b527dbe3f1c447a942f69/moment.js)